# How can I solve $\int x\exp(-Tx^a)\,dx$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

How can I solve $$\int x\exp(-T x^a)\,dx$$

($T$ and $a$ are variables.)

In WolframAlpha, the answer is

$$-x^2(Tx^a)^{-2/a}\,\frac{\Gamma(2/a,Tx^a)}a$$

I don't know why.

Comment: Because WA does not know how to simplify as long as the sign of $T$ is not given (same for $x$). Then this expression. Look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x+exp(-T+x%5Ea) ; there is a part with the result assuming $T>0$ and $x >0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are considering $$I=\int x\,e^{-T \, x^a } dx$$
Let 
$$T \, x^a=y \implies x=\left(\frac{y}{T}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\implies dx=\frac{\left(\frac{y}{T}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}-1}}{a T}\,dy$$ this makes
$$I=\frac 1 {a T^{\frac 2a}}\int e^{-y} y^{\frac{2}{a}-1} \,dy$$ and then the incomplete gamma function since
$$\int e^{-y} y^{\frac{2}{a}-1} \,dy=-\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{a},y\right)$$ Go back to $x$ for the result.